# Поиск email в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, например:

```
ivanov@ivan
sidorov@mail.ru
petrov_kolya.ru
```

Как мне вытащить из этого теста только адрес эл почты sidorov@mail.ru? При том, что домен может меняться (например не mail а yandex), и зона может меняться (например не ru а com), то есть постоянны только символы @ и .

Даже не столь важно вытащить мэйл, сколько проверить, есть ли мэйл в этом тексте, например что то типа этого:

```
text = 'ivanov@ivan sidorov@mail.ru petrov_kolya.ru'
word = '*****@*****.***'
if word in text:
    print ('ok!')
else:
    pass
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/5741205

Comment: В общем случае, задача непростая, Например, адрес может быть записан кириллицей.

Comment: уточните задачу. В общем случае, можно быть уверенным, что человек свою почту дал, только отправив письмо со ссылкой для подтверждения (всё остальное не достаточно: ни [монстровый Perl regex на основе RFC 5322](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917982/4279), который или слишком много/разрешает или наоборот не поддерживает адреса из реальной практики; ни проверка DNS, MX, ни поддержка punycode, utf-8(Unicode) ни проверка что не disposable адрес, ни проверка на основе частного сервиса, итд).

Comment: ^\w+@\w+\..{2,3}(.{2,3})?$ 

Если так попробовать?

Comment: почему вы думаете, что `ivanov@ivan` это неверный адрес, а `ivanov@example.abc` верный?

Comment: `some-e.mail+abc@local` // cc @nick_gabpe

Comment: Куда будет доставлено @local? Если оно недоставляемо, то оно и неприемлемо. Я тут недавно рмрфнул папку экзима с 90ГБ локальной почты не читая)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = "ivanov@ivan sidorov@mail.ru petrov_kolya.ru"
pattern = r"sidorov@([\w\.-]+)(\.[\w\.]+)"

if re.search(pattern, text):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Решил сделать через регулярные выражения(других вариантов не знаю).

Comment: `some-e.mail+abc@local`

Comment: имейл ivanov@***.* ваша регулярка не найдет.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = 'ivanov@ivan sidorov@mail.ru petrov_kolya.ru'
pattern = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'

if re.search(pattern, text):
    print('Email found in the text!')
else:
    print('No email found in the text.')
```